# Blueshift and redshift of a radially infalling photon

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, redshift

An observer, initially at rest in infinity, is radially infalling through a  Schwarschild black hole of mass M. Also a photon is radially infalling, almost cathing up the observer at a radial distance $r_o$.

If the energy of the photon at infinity is $E = \hbar w_{\infty}$. What is the frequency w of the photon that the observer measures in r_0?

My calculations give that $w_{obs} = w_{\infty}(1 - 2M/ r_o)^{-1/2}$. So $w_{obs} > w_{\infty}$. Is that right? For the photon to be redshifted, the result should have been $w_{obs} < w_{\infty}$ ?.

I don´t understnad if it is reshifted or blueshifted and what happens on the event horizont. I understand that an observer outside the black hole would see the photon redshifted and and observer closer to the black hole than the photon would see the photon blueshifted but I don´t understnad my results.

Thanks.

Comment: Your formula is for the gravitational time dilation only. While it is correct, it applies only to an observer hovering at $r_o$, but not to the one in a free fall. To account for the free fall, you should add the velocity redshift to your gravitational blueshift formula.